# Why integrate celery with flask? What are the benefits? Why not use them separately?

Tags: flask, celery

Why integrate celery with flask? What are the benefits? Why not use them separately?

Can you share several examples why do you need to integrate them, and no just use them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celery is not tightly integrated with flask, although you can use flask configuration to update celery configuration values. Django has good integration with celery, in a sense that there is a recommended way of configuring celery with django. Celery is just distributed task queue which comes with extra features like retries, task_limits.

You can always use celery separately to just execute tasks on a different machine/process. Celery solves a problem of asynchronous job execution. You can have different number of celery processes and flask processes and scale them independently depending on your traffic and latency requirements. And you shouldn't use celery when it's an overkill, as it requires you setup a dedicated broker for message passing. You might just get the job done using threading, multiprocessing, green threads or coroutines.